# GetCursorPos Address below Shape Object

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which displays the cursor position in pixels and the equivalent Range on the spreadsheet. As soon as I put the cursor over a Shape Object the code gives an error because it can't retrieve the cell value below the Shape. Is there any workaround to that? Below is the code:

```
Public Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Public Type POINTAPI
Xcoord As Long
Ycoord As Long
End Type

Sub SetKey()

    Application.OnKey "a", "PositionXY"

End Sub


Sub PositionXY()
Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
Dim rng As Range

Do
GetCursorPos llCoord
Set rng = GetRange(llCoord.Xcoord, llCoord.Ycoord)

Range("A1").Value = "X: " & llCoord.Xcoord & " Y: " & llCoord.Ycoord
Range("A2").Value = rng.Address
DoEvents
Loop
End Sub

Function GetRange(x As Long, y As Long) As Range
    Set GetRange = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(x, y)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you consider hiding shapes when running your code and then making them visible?

Comment: I tried doing that, it worked fine but shapes flickering is something i wanted to avoid, as the point of this code is somehow "visual"

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019337/how-to-select-cell-on-the-back-of-a-shape-object-click-through-that-shape

Comment: I tried both of the codes provided on this links and none seem to work. Both error on `Mouse`. Perhaps I didn't declare something I should have or added a library? Or even, can I just execute that code or is there another way to call a function?

Comment: What you are doing is a bit uncommon so you will not find many sources and I understand your pain. I cannot figure out whether the code works or not since one needs to have some more info to debug. I would still choose the simplest way and hide the shapes before the code and make them visible after. There should not be any flickering etc, you should control it by `application.sccreenupdating` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it around by placing a Label over the Shape object, and assigning the following code to it:

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

rng = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Label1").TopLeftCell.Address
Range("A1").Value = rng

End Sub
```